# Crystal Reports Question

Tags: crystal-reports, report

```
//Using Small Business Code from PO Record in Subreport Accumulate Associated $
numbervar BC1;
WhilePrintingRecords;
shared stringvar BC;
// added following 2 statements to prevent doubling value on last record 10/23/06 (WET)
if shared stringvar BC = "   BC1" and not onlastrecord then BC1 := BC1+{@PTEXT$};
if shared stringvar BC = "   BC1" and onlastrecord then BC1 := BC1+{@PTEXT$}/2;
// deleted following statement to prevent doubling value on last record 10/23/06 (WET)
// if shared stringvar BC = "   BC1" then BC1TOT := BC1TOT+{@PEXT$};
BC1
```

I'm getting an error in the `BC1+{@PTEXT$};` that states "A number is required here." On another copy of a crystal reports form, I have the same code, but no error. Any Ideas here?

Comment: What are the contents of `@TEXT$` in this report?  What are the contents of `shared stringvar BC` in the other report?

Comment: Can you show us your formula for `{@PTEXT$}`? That's probably where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `BC1+{@PTEXT$}` cannot be added if `{@PTEXT$}` is a string (if {@PTEXT$}="  1", Crystal may recognize that as a string, not a number).  You could change that to `cdbl(BC1+{@PTEXT$})`
2. Perhaps you have a record for which `{@PTEXT$}` is null? Since BC1+null=null, that could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are combining a number with text.  You must Convert BC1 to text or the text to a number if possible.

Comment: Not quite, PTEXT is a numberic value based off a calculation. Im attempting to show the amount of a number value. BC1 BC2, BC3, etc. depending on how many show up in the report, will show some sort of money value.

Comment: @gabrielVA well the error your getting tell me that PTEXT is being translated as STRING.   Just for giggles convert it to number and see what happens.